# Postman rest client is giving 404 error every time in response

Tags: postman, tomcat8

When I am running same url("http://localhost:4047/webServicesDemo/webapi/injectdemo/context") in tomcat configured in eclipse it it working fine. While getting 404 error every time in postman rest client.
Please put some light on it.
Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHuR3.png)

Comment: Maybe you are missing some headers from postman request.

Comment: No, by same url I am getting fine output in eclipse.

Comment: Like I said, there are some *headers* in request and maybe they are missing when you send request from postman. Do you use the same HTTP method in both cases? (`GET`, `POST`)

Comment: @tilz0R, just now I have checked it again, I am using proper header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Apache does not work with other ports. You need to set the port of your google chrome in httpconfig file of Apache Server.

Comment: I know it but I am not getting the actual reason why tomcat, configured in eclipse is working but when I am trying to access the same url from browser it is not accepting showing error.